# Putting three.js animation inside of div

Tags: html5-canvas, three.js

This is three.js animation code example:

```
<script defer="defer">
  var angularSpeed = 0.2; 
  var lastTime = 0;
  function animate(){
    var time = (new Date()).getTime();
    var timeDiff = time - lastTime;
    var angleChange = angularSpeed * timeDiff * 2 * Math.PI / 1000;
    plane.rotation.z += angleChange;
    lastTime = time;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
        animate();
    });
  }
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.y = -450;
  camera.position.z = 400;
  camera.rotation.x = 45 * (Math.PI / 180);
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(300, 300), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
  plane.overdraw = true;
  scene.add(plane);
  animate();
 </script>
```

I would like to bind this animation code to some specific div via div id. So, animation would be displayed inside of div. That would allow me to easily manipulate animation location with css. I was having in mind something like this:

html:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
// do stuff here
```

But I haven't found a way to do something like this with three.js. As you can see in code example, there is no canvas element that I can refer to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use a pattern like the following:

```
<div id="canvas"></div>

#canvas {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: static; /* fixed or static */
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}

container = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
document.body.appendChild( container );

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( 200, 200 );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uf4c0ws9/

Also see [THREE.js Ray Intersect fails by adding div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542175/three-js-ray-intersect-fails-by-adding-div/13544277#13544277)

three.js r.150

Comment: But what if width and height are different. I need them to be different but that actually change the aspect ratio of height and width. Thus, circles appear to be oval.

Comment: @sahilshekhawat `renderer.setSize( canvas_width, canvas_height );` and make sure the camera `aspect` is correct.

Comment: I am using ``setSize`` with perspective camera.  Didn't thought about camera's aspect ratio.  Thanks

Comment: In `renderer.setSize` why hardwire `canvas_width` and `canvas_height` rather than getting values from the `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` properties of the `container` object?

Answer (score 2):

**If you don't want to hardcode renderer size then below piece of code can help you.**

I am dynamically calculating canvas height and width and then accordingly setting the renderer's size and camera's position.

CSS

```
            #canvas {
             background-color: #FFF;
             width: 200px;
             height:200px;
             border: 1px solid black;
              }
```

HTML

```
<div id="canvas"/>
```

JavaScript

```
         //Add Renderer
         renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
         var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
         var w = container.offsetWidth;
         var h = container.offsetHeight;
         renderer.setSize(w, h);
         container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        
        //Add Camera
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, w / h, 2, 1000 );
        camera.position.z = 400;

        //Create Scene with geometry, material-> mesh
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry( 200, 3 );
        material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, wireframe: true, wireframeLinewidth: 1 } );
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( mesh );
```

Comment: I would prefer WebGLRenderer over CanvasRenderer unless there was a good reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation of the pattern shown by WestLangley:

HTML:

```
<div class="relative h-256 w-256">
    <div id="scene"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#scene {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.relative {
    position: relative;
}

.h-256 {
    height: 256px;
}

.w-256 {
    width: 256px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
this.mount = document.querySelector('#scene');

this.width = document.querySelector('#scene').offsetWidth;
this.height = document.querySelector('#scene').offsetHeight;

...

this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });

this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

this.renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height);

this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
```

Three.JS renders the `<canvas>` element inside the `div#scene` container, which is absolute positioned to fill the wrapper. The size is controlled by the wrapper div's dimensions.