# Toggling Dark mode button stops working after AJAX calls in click event listener (all logic wrapped in an IIFE)

Tags: javascript, ajax, event-handling, dom-events

For my personal blogging site (https://victorfeight.com/) served behind Cloudflare pages, I'm using Eleventy with a custom script that include dark mode toggling logic, SPA-like page switches with AJAX, and search functionality with Elasticlunr and JavaScript . As I am new to JavaScript Web development and opted not to use a Framework to achieve SPA page switches, I decided to implement all the logic into a single file, wrapped in an IIFE (passing in window and document). I'm wondering if this is the standard way to implement this sort of logic together, or if I should be using webpack or a more modern solution. I'm also wondering if it's possible to load dark mode/light mode script logic and search mode logic per page, in spite of using an AJAX url-switching logic.

First issue: Certain click event handling logic seems to be interrupting my new dark mode toggle, introduced in the same file.
I implemented logic found here for dark mode: https://jec.fyi/blog/supporting-dark-mode
And I implemented search functionality using logic found here:  https://www.belter.io/eleventy-search/

I have the following HTML in my Liquid template, which is loaded by default:

```
  <div class="col-xl-6 px-0">
    <div class="p-0 p-md-0 m-0 text-white">
    <object type="text/html"
        style="width: 100%;height: 30rem;min-width: 378px;" id="icosahedron"
        data="scripts/icosahedron.html">
    </object>
    </div>
      <!-- <iframe style="width: 100%;height: 30rem;min-width: 378px;" scrolling="no" id="icosahedron"
        src="scripts/icosahedron.html" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
  </div>
```

I have a light mode version of scripts/icosahedron.html, which loads in  scripts/script.js (light version) via  and  scripts/icosahedron_dark.html which loads in scripts/script_dark.js (dark version).

I want to selectively toggle which script is loaded depending on a press of my light-mode/dark-mode button.

The logic I implemented for the page switching (which seems to be interrupting the dark mode toggle wrapped in the same IIFE) I found from here:
https://github.com/learosema/eleventy-mini-spa

```
  /**
   * Load content into page without a whole page reload
   * @param {string} href URL to route to
   * @param {boolean} pushState whether to call history.pushState or not
   */
  function load(href, pushState) {
    const container = $("main");

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      fetchJSON();
      const d = xhr.responseXML;
      const dTitle = d.title || "";
      const dContainer = $("main", d);
      container.innerHTML = (dContainer && dContainer.innerHTML) || "";
      document.title = dTitle;
      if (pushState) {
        history.pushState({}, dTitle, href);
      }
      container.focus();
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
      // fallback to normal link behaviour
      document.location.href = href;
      return;
    };
    xhr.open("GET", href);
    xhr.responseType = "document";
    xhr.send();
  }

  function $(sel, con) {
    return (con || document).querySelector(sel);
  }

  /**
   * Search for a parent anchor tag outside a clicked event target
   *
   * @param {HTMLElement} el the clicked event target.
   * @param {number} maxNests max number of levels to go up.
   * @returns the anchor tag or null
   */
  function findAnchorTag(el, maxNests = 3) {
    for (let i = maxNests; el && i > 0; --i, el = el.parentNode) {
      if (el.nodeName === "A") {
        return el;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  const links = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link");
  // Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
      if (current[0]) {
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
      }
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    let baseUrl = $('meta[name="x-base-url"]')?.getAttribute("content") || "/";
    const el = findAnchorTag(evt.target);
    const href = el?.getAttribute("href");
    if (el && href) {
      if (
        href.startsWith("#") ||
        el.getAttribute("target") === "_blank" ||
        /\.\w+$/.test(href)
      ) {
        // eleventy urls in this configuration do not have extensions like .html
        // if they have, or if target _blank is set, or they are a hash link,
        // then do nothing.
        return;
      }

      if (href.startsWith("/")) {
        icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron_dark.html");
      }

      // if the URL starts with the base url, do the SPA handling
      if (href.startsWith(baseUrl)) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        load(href, true);
      }
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener("popstate", function (e) {
    load(document.location.pathname, false);
  });

  fetchJSON();
```

As a side note, I found I had to repeat my fetchJSON() function on each page switch as well, to get search working, I'm wondering what would be best practice for this, as I'm also getting "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null fetchJSON [https://victorfeight.com/scripts/mini-spa.js:9"](https://victorfeight.com/scripts/mini-spa.js:9%22) leading from onload and load in the error stack before the search logic is called.

Note I've added the following to   click event listener to test, but it seemingly does nothing:

```
if (href.startsWith("/")) {
        icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron_dark.html");
}
```

Here's the click handling logic:

```
  window.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    let baseUrl = $('meta[name="x-base-url"]')?.getAttribute("content") || "/";
    const el = findAnchorTag(evt.target);
    const href = el?.getAttribute("href");
    if (el && href) {
      if (
        href.startsWith("#") ||
        el.getAttribute("target") === "_blank" ||
        /\.\w+$/.test(href)
      ) {
        // eleventy urls in this configuration do not have extensions like .html
        // if they have, or if target _blank is set, or they are a hash link,
        // then do nothing.
        return;
      }

      if (href.startsWith("/")) {
        icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron_dark.html");
      }

      // if the URL starts with the base url, do the SPA handling
      if (href.startsWith(baseUrl)) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        load(href, true);
      }
    }
  });
```

What I've tried, this is my full color mode logic:

```
  "use strict";
  const icosa = document.getElementById("icosahedron");
  function changeColor() {
    const bodyEl = document.body;
    const themeStylesheet = document.getElementById("theme");
    const themeToggle = document.getElementById("moon-1");
    const DARK = "dark";
    const LIGHT = "light";
    const COLOR_SCHEME_CHANGED = "colorSchemeChanged";

    themeToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const isDark = bodyEl.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
      const mode = isDark ? DARK : LIGHT;
      sessionStorage.setItem("jec.color-scheme", mode);

      if (isDark) {
        icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron_dark.html");
        themeToggle.className = "far fa-sun fa-2x";
        themeToggle.title = themeToggle.title.replace(DARK, LIGHT);
        if (themeStylesheet)
          themeStylesheet.href = themeStylesheet.href.replace(LIGHT, DARK);
      } else {
        icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron.html");
        themeToggle.className = "far fa-moon fa-2x";
        themeToggle.title = themeToggle.title.replace(LIGHT, DARK);
        if (themeStylesheet)
          themeStylesheet.href = themeStylesheet.href.replace(DARK, LIGHT);
      }

      themeToggle.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent(COLOR_SCHEME_CHANGED, { detail: mode })
      );
    });
  }

  changeColor();
  function init() {
    const DARK = "dark";
    const LIGHT = "light";
    const isSystemDarkMode =
      matchMedia && window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;

    let mode = sessionStorage.getItem("jec.color-scheme");

    if (!mode && isSystemDarkMode) {
      mode = DARK;
    } else {
      mode = mode || LIGHT;
    }

    if (mode === DARK) {
      icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron_dark.html");
      document.getElementById("moon-1").click();
    }
  }

  // run the code
  init();
  const pressEnter = (e) => {
    const searchField = document.getElementById("searchField");
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      if (searchField) {
        searchField && searchField.blur();
      }
    }
  };
```

What I added to get color mode working, in my init() function I modify the data attribute to point to the correct file:

```
if (mode === DARK) {
  icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron_dark.html");
```

And in my relevant changed change color function:

```
  if (isDark) {
    icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron_dark.html");
    themeToggle.className = "far fa-sun fa-2x";
    themeToggle.title = themeToggle.title.replace(DARK, LIGHT);
    if (themeStylesheet)
      themeStylesheet.href = themeStylesheet.href.replace(LIGHT, DARK);
  } else {
    icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron.html");
```

[image: Bug]

Now the logic works on the Front page. But as soon as I switch pages using the top navigation, and back to home page, the logic to selectively load the scripts stops working, I'm assuming an issue with scope.

So my question is, how can I get this dark mode script toggle logic working nicely with this link page switching logic? And is wrapping the logic of all three scripts in an IIFE the best approach, or should I be looking for other techniques to modularize this better? Currently, Production build served via Cloudflare pages is not loading the selective dark mode script logic at all, only local does. The screenshot included is from local. I'm also interested in how I can selectively load CSS for my search background image on dark mode toggle. I appreciate any advice.

Here is the full script, for completion sake:

```
(function (window, document) {
  "use strict";
  const icosa = document.getElementById("icosahedron");
  function changeColor() {
    const bodyEl = document.body;
    const themeStylesheet = document.getElementById("theme");
    const themeToggle = document.getElementById("moon-1");
    const DARK = "dark";
    const LIGHT = "light";
    const COLOR_SCHEME_CHANGED = "colorSchemeChanged";

    themeToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const isDark = bodyEl.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
      const mode = isDark ? DARK : LIGHT;
      sessionStorage.setItem("jec.color-scheme", mode);

      if (isDark) {
        icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron_dark.html");
        themeToggle.className = "far fa-sun fa-2x";
        themeToggle.title = themeToggle.title.replace(DARK, LIGHT);
        if (themeStylesheet)
          themeStylesheet.href = themeStylesheet.href.replace(LIGHT, DARK);
      } else {
        icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron.html");
        themeToggle.className = "far fa-moon fa-2x";
        themeToggle.title = themeToggle.title.replace(LIGHT, DARK);
        if (themeStylesheet)
          themeStylesheet.href = themeStylesheet.href.replace(DARK, LIGHT);
      }

      themeToggle.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent(COLOR_SCHEME_CHANGED, { detail: mode })
      );
    });
  }

  changeColor();
  function init() {
    const DARK = "dark";
    const LIGHT = "light";
    const isSystemDarkMode =
      matchMedia && window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;

    let mode = sessionStorage.getItem("jec.color-scheme");

    if (!mode && isSystemDarkMode) {
      mode = DARK;
    } else {
      mode = mode || LIGHT;
    }

    if (mode === DARK) {
      icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron_dark.html");
      document.getElementById("moon-1").click();
    }
  }

  // run the code
  init();
  const pressEnter = (e) => {
    const searchField = document.getElementById("searchField");
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      if (searchField) {
        searchField && searchField.blur();
      }
    }
  };

  const search = (e) => {
    const cardHolder = document.getElementById("card-holder");
    if (e.target.value) {
      cardHolder.style.display = "none";
    }
    const results = window.searchIndex.search(e.target.value, {
      bool: "AND",
      expand: true,
    });

    const resEl = document.getElementById("searchResults");
    const noResultsEl = document.getElementById("noResultsFound");

    resEl.innerHTML = "";
    if (Object.keys(results).length !== 0) {
      noResultsEl.style.display = "none";
      cardHolder.style.display = "none";
      results.map((r) => {
        const { id, title, categories, excerpt, date } = r.doc;
        const el = document.createElement("div");
        el.setAttribute(
          "class",
          "archive-card card border border-light shadow-0"
        );
        el.style.display = "flex";

        resEl.appendChild(el);

        const header = document.createElement("div");
        header.setAttribute("id", "archive-header");
        header.setAttribute("class", "card-header border-0");
        el.appendChild(header);

        const h3 = document.createElement("h3");
        h3.setAttribute("class", "card-title pb-3");
        h3.style.textDecoration = "underline";
        header.appendChild(h3);

        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute("href", id);
        a.setAttribute("class", "text-black");
        a.textContent = title;

        h3.appendChild(a);

        const dateSection = document.createElement("div");
        dateSection.setAttribute("class", "category-section text-muted");
        var dateString = date;
        dateSection.innerHTML += dateString;
        header.appendChild(dateSection);

        console.log(categories);

        var catString = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
          if (i === 0) {
            catString += `&nbsp; &nbsp;[<a href="/category/${categories[i]}">${categories[i]}</a>, `;
          } else if (i != categories.length - 1) {
            catString += `<a href="/category/${categories[i]}">${categories[i]}</a>, `;
          } else {
            catString += `<a href="/category/${categories[i]}">${categories[i]}</a>]`;
          }
        }
        // header.innerHTML += catString;

        dateSection.innerHTML += catString;

        const cardBody = document.createElement("div");
        header.setAttribute("class", "card-body");
        el.appendChild(cardBody);
        const excerptP = document.createElement("p");
        excerptP.setAttribute("class", "card-text");
        excerptP.innerHTML += excerpt;
        cardBody.appendChild(excerptP);
      });
    } else {
      noResultsEl.style.display = "block";
      cardHolder.style.display = "block";
    }
  };

  function fetchJSON() {
    fetch("/search-index.json").then((response) =>
      response.json().then((rawIndex) => {
        window.searchIndex = elasticlunr.Index.load(rawIndex);
        document
          .getElementById("searchField")
          .addEventListener("keyup", search);
        document
          .getElementById("searchField")
          .addEventListener("keydown", pressEnter);
      })
    );
  }

  fetchJSON();

  /**
   * Load content into page without a whole page reload
   * @param {string} href URL to route to
   * @param {boolean} pushState whether to call history.pushState or not
   */
  function load(href, pushState) {
    const container = $("main");

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      fetchJSON();
      const d = xhr.responseXML;
      const dTitle = d.title || "";
      const dContainer = $("main", d);
      container.innerHTML = (dContainer && dContainer.innerHTML) || "";
      document.title = dTitle;
      if (pushState) {
        history.pushState({}, dTitle, href);
      }
      container.focus();
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
      // fallback to normal link behaviour
      document.location.href = href;
      return;
    };
    xhr.open("GET", href);
    xhr.responseType = "document";
    xhr.send();
  }

  function $(sel, con) {
    return (con || document).querySelector(sel);
  }

  /**
   * Search for a parent anchor tag outside a clicked event target
   *
   * @param {HTMLElement} el the clicked event target.
   * @param {number} maxNests max number of levels to go up.
   * @returns the anchor tag or null
   */
  function findAnchorTag(el, maxNests = 3) {
    for (let i = maxNests; el && i > 0; --i, el = el.parentNode) {
      if (el.nodeName === "A") {
        return el;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  const links = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link");
  // Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
      if (current[0]) {
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
      }
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    let baseUrl = $('meta[name="x-base-url"]')?.getAttribute("content") || "/";
    const el = findAnchorTag(evt.target);
    const href = el?.getAttribute("href");
    if (el && href) {
      if (
        href.startsWith("#") ||
        el.getAttribute("target") === "_blank" ||
        /\.\w+$/.test(href)
      ) {
        // eleventy urls in this configuration do not have extensions like .html
        // if they have, or if target _blank is set, or they are a hash link,
        // then do nothing.
        return;
      }

      if (href.startsWith("/")) {
        icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron_dark.html");
      }

      // if the URL starts with the base url, do the SPA handling
      if (href.startsWith(baseUrl)) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        load(href, true);
      }
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener("popstate", function (e) {
    load(document.location.pathname, false);
  });

  fetchJSON();
})(window, document);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me take this step my step.

First issue: The click event handling logic

I re-implemented all of my javascript logic into separate files, which get minified by Rollup.js now.

Here is my new rollup build config:

```
import path from "path";
import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";

let fileDest = `mdb.min`;
const external = ["@popperjs/core"];
const plugins = [terser()];
const globals = {
  "@popperjs/core": "Popper",
};

export default [
  {
    input: path.resolve(__dirname, `_11ty_scripts/js/mdb.free.js`),
    output: {
      file: path.resolve(__dirname, `scripts/${fileDest}.js`),
      format: "umd",
      name: "bootstrap",
      globals,
    },
    external,
    plugins,
  },
  {
    input: ["_11ty_scripts/search.js"],
    output: [
      {
        file: "scripts/search.min.js",
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
        plugins: [terser()],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    input: ["_11ty_scripts/main.js"],
    output: [
      {
        file: "scripts/min.js",
        format: "iife",
        sourcemap: true,
        plugins: [terser()],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    input: ["_11ty_scripts/colorToggle.js"],
    output: [
      {
        file: "scripts/colorToggle.min.js",
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
        plugins: [terser()],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

This is bundling a custom version of mdb.free.js which uses some static analysis and tree-shaking to remove unused code from result, which then gets minified by terser().

I separated search.js and main.js into their own external files. A lot of the main.js logic I took from https://github.com/google/eleventy-high-performance-blog and I'm replacing my original spa-like ajax switches with prefetching the links on hover:

```
const exposed = {};
if (location.search) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = location.href;
  a.search = "";
  history.replaceState(null, null, a.href);
}

function tweet_(url) {
  open(
    "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url),
    "_blank"
  );
}
function tweet(anchor) {
  tweet_(anchor.getAttribute("href"));
}
expose("tweet", tweet);

function share(anchor) {
  var url = anchor.getAttribute("href");
  event.preventDefault();
  tweet_(url);
  //if (navigator.share) {
  //  navigator.share({
  //    url: url,
  //  });
  //} else if (navigator.clipboard) {
  //  navigator.clipboard.writeText(url);
  //  message("Article URL copied to clipboard.");
  //} else {
  //  tweet_(url);
  //}
}
expose("share", share);

function message(msg) {
  var dialog = document.getElementById("message");
  dialog.textContent = msg;
  dialog.setAttribute("open", "");
  setTimeout(function () {
    dialog.removeAttribute("open");
  }, 3000);
}

function prefetch(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName != "A") {
    return;
  }
  if (e.target.origin != location.origin) {
    return;
  }
  /**
   * Return the given url with no fragment
   * @param {string} url potentially containing a fragment
   * @return {string} url without fragment
   */
  const removeUrlFragment = (url) => url.split("#")[0];
  if (
    removeUrlFragment(window.location.href) === removeUrlFragment(e.target.href)
  ) {
    return;
  }
  var l = document.createElement("link");
  l.rel = "prefetch";
  l.href = e.target.href;
  document.head.appendChild(l);
}
document.documentElement.addEventListener("mouseover", prefetch, {
  capture: true,
  passive: true,
});
document.documentElement.addEventListener("touchstart", prefetch, {
  capture: true,
  passive: true,
});

const GA_ID = document.documentElement.getAttribute("ga-id");
window.ga =
  window.ga ||
  function () {
    if (!GA_ID) {
      return;
    }
    (ga.q = ga.q || []).push(arguments);
  };
ga.l = +new Date();
ga("create", GA_ID, "auto");
ga("set", "transport", "beacon");
var timeout = setTimeout(
  (onload = function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    ga("send", "pageview");
  }),
  1000
);

var ref = +new Date();
function ping(event) {
  var now = +new Date();
  if (now - ref < 1000) {
    return;
  }
  ga("send", {
    hitType: "event",
    eventCategory: "page",
    eventAction: event.type,
    eventLabel: Math.round((now - ref) / 1000),
  });
  ref = now;
}
addEventListener("pagehide", ping);
addEventListener("visibilitychange", ping);

/**
 * Injects a script into document.head
 * @param {string} src path of script to be injected in <head>
 * @return {Promise} Promise object that resolves on script load event
 */
const dynamicScriptInject = (src) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = src;
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    script.addEventListener("load", () => {
      resolve(script);
    });
  });
};

// Script web-vitals.js will be injected dynamically if user opts-in to sending CWV data.
const sendWebVitals = document.currentScript.getAttribute("data-cwv-src");

if (/web-vitals.js/.test(sendWebVitals)) {
  dynamicScriptInject(`${window.location.origin}/scripts/web-vitals.js`)
    .then(() => {
      webVitals.getCLS(sendToGoogleAnalytics);
      webVitals.getFID(sendToGoogleAnalytics);
      webVitals.getLCP(sendToGoogleAnalytics);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

addEventListener(
  "click",
  function (e) {
    var button = e.target.closest("button");
    if (!button) {
      return;
    }
    ga("send", {
      hitType: "event",
      eventCategory: "button",
      eventAction: button.getAttribute("aria-label") || button.textContent,
    });
  },
  true
);
var selectionTimeout;
addEventListener(
  "selectionchange",
  function () {
    clearTimeout(selectionTimeout);
    var text = String(document.getSelection()).trim();
    if (text.split(/[\s\n\r]+/).length < 3) {
      return;
    }
    selectionTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
      ga("send", {
        hitType: "event",
        eventCategory: "selection",
        eventAction: text,
      });
    }, 2000);
  },
  true
);


function expose(name, fn) {
  exposed[name] = fn;
}

addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const handler = e.target.closest("[on-click]");
  if (!handler) {
    return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  const name = handler.getAttribute("on-click");
  const fn = exposed[name];
  if (!fn) {
    throw new Error("Unknown handler" + name);
  }
  fn(handler);
});

function removeBlurredImage(img) {
  // Ensure the browser doesn't try to draw the placeholder when the real image is present.
  img.style.backgroundImage = "none";
}
document.body.addEventListener(
  "load",
  (e) => {
    if (e.target.tagName != "IMG") {
      return;
    }
    removeBlurredImage(e.target);
  },
  /* capture */ "true"
);
for (let img of document.querySelectorAll("img")) {
  if (img.complete) {
    removeBlurredImage(img);
  }
}
```

This is all rolled into an IIFE by rollup and served on every page.
There's a lot going on there but essentially it's logic for twitter sharing and prefetching of links, though it does add some click handling logic that needs to be carefully sidestepped by my colorToggle logic.

For colorToggle, I reimplemented my original logic which swapped between two href stylesheets using javascript, to now swap between two color-mode attributes in CSS and remember choice by localStorage. This improved speed significantly and allowed smooth page changes. This is all bundled into a CommonJS format by rollup and served on every page, alongside the other IIFE.

```
// This code assumes a Light Mode default
function checkColor() {
  if (
    /* This condition checks whether the user has set a site preference for dark mode OR a OS-level preference for Dark Mode AND no site preference */
    localStorage.getItem('color-mode') === 'dark' ||
    (window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches &&
     !localStorage.getItem('color-mode'))) {
    // if true, set the site to Dark Mode
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('color-mode', 'dark')
  }
}
checkColor();

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
// const icosa = document.getElementById("icosahedron");
  if (
    /* This condition checks whether the user has set a site preference for dark mode OR a OS-level preference for Dark Mode AND no site preference */
    localStorage.getItem('color-mode') === 'dark' ||
    (window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches &&
     !localStorage.getItem('color-mode'))) {
    // if true, set the site to Dark Mode
    // icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron_dark.html");
  }

const toggleColorMode = e => {
  // Switch to Light Mode
  if (e.currentTarget.classList.contains("light--hidden")) {
      // Sets the custom HTML attribute
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("color-mode", "light");
    // icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron.html");

      //Sets the user's preference in local storage
    localStorage.setItem("color-mode", "light")
    return;
}
  
  /* Switch to Dark Mode
  Sets the custom HTML attribute */
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("color-mode", "dark");
  // icosa.setAttribute("data", "scripts/icosahedron_dark.html");

// Sets the user's preference in local storage
localStorage.setItem("color-mode", "dark");
};

// Get the buttons in the DOM
let toggleIcons = document.querySelectorAll("#darkmode, #lightmode");
// Set up event listeners
toggleIcons.forEach(i => {
    i.addEventListener("click", toggleColorMode);
}); 

});
```

In the end, the issue turned out to be that my javascript was trying to find the icon before it was loaded onto the DOM. So I added a DOMContentLoaded function which waited til the icon loaded before selecting it. I added a function at the top which checks that the system is dark or light mode using prefers-color-scheme and localStorage matches, and put this script high in my HTML head.

My search functionality is all wrapped in an IIFE still for browser compatibility:

```
(function (window, document) {
  "use strict";

  const cardHolder = document.getElementById("card-holder");
  const searchField = document.getElementById("searchField");
  const pressEnter = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      searchField && searchField.blur();
    }
  };
  const search = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value) {
      cardHolder.style.display = "none";
    }
    const results = window.searchIndex.search(e.target.value, {
      bool: "AND",
      expand: true,
    });

    const resEl = document.getElementById("searchResults");
    const noResultsEl = document.getElementById("noResultsFound");

    resEl.innerHTML = "";
    if (Object.keys(results).length !== 0) {
      noResultsEl.style.display = "none";
      cardHolder.style.display = "none";
      results.map((r) => {
        const { id, title, categories, excerpt, date } = r.doc;
        const el = document.createElement("div");
        el.setAttribute(
          "class",
          "archive-card card border border-light shadow-0"
        );
        el.style.display = "flex";

        resEl.appendChild(el);

        const header = document.createElement("div");
        header.setAttribute("id", "archive-header");
        header.setAttribute("class", "card-header border-0");
        el.appendChild(header);

        const h3 = document.createElement("h3");
        h3.setAttribute("class", "card-title pb-3");
        h3.style.textDecoration = "underline";
        header.appendChild(h3);

        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.setAttribute("href", id);
        a.setAttribute("class", "text-black");
        a.textContent = title;

        h3.appendChild(a);

        const dateSection = document.createElement("div");
        dateSection.setAttribute("class", "category-section text-muted");
        var dateString = date;
        dateSection.innerHTML += dateString;
        header.appendChild(dateSection);

        console.log(categories);

        var catString = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
          if (i === 0) {
            catString += `&nbsp; &nbsp;[<a href="/category/${categories[i]}">${categories[i]}</a>, `;
          } else if (i != categories.length - 1) {
            catString += `<a href="/category/${categories[i]}">${categories[i]}</a>, `;
          } else {
            catString += `<a href="/category/${categories[i]}">${categories[i]}</a>]`;
          }
        }
        // header.innerHTML += catString;
        
        dateSection.innerHTML += catString;
        

        const cardBody = document.createElement("div");
        header.setAttribute("class", "card-body");
        el.appendChild(cardBody);
        const excerptP = document.createElement("p");
        excerptP.setAttribute("class", "card-text");
        excerptP.innerHTML += excerpt;
        cardBody.appendChild(excerptP);

      });
    } else {
      noResultsEl.style.display = "block";
      cardHolder.style.display = "block";
    }
  };

  fetch("/search-index.json").then((response) =>
    response.json().then((rawIndex) => {
      window.searchIndex = elasticlunr.Index.load(rawIndex);
      document.getElementById("searchField").addEventListener("keyup", search);
      document.getElementById("searchField").addEventListener("keydown", pressEnter);

    })
  );

})(window, document);
```

Rollup turns this to CommonJS and minifies it alongside my other JS, to be served only on the search page.

The only thing that's now not working, is toggling automatically the background color of the embedded HTML object which has an HTML script loading the Three.js animation, but that's a bit tricker and best saved for its own question now that everything else is working.

EDIT:
Forgot to mention, Cloudflare Pages was serving an external Javascript folder inadvertently that I caught after comparing the two site folders (local and remote) using Chrome dev tools. After purging Cloudflare pages Cache and refreshing, deleting cookies and site data the color was saved on page change (the additional JS files that were being served by Cloudflare had caused scoping mess issues with my colorToggle functionality).

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question regarding toggling of the embedded HTML background color which had an HTML script loading the Three.js animation with some third party CSS.

I followed advice from the answer here:  [Putting three.js animation inside of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507525/putting-three-js-animation-inside-of-div/17507839#17507839)

I was able to remove the need for the HTML and CSS in an embedded object and add the CSS myself, then dive into the Three.js code and add the dom element addition myself.
Now it's embedded and changes colors dynamically.