# Three.js click object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been trying to make [this](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html) example work for me. I'm almost there.
My problem is that I'm not using a full screen canvas. I'm using a smaller div that might be placed differently depending on resolution.

What I have working is getting the coordinates of the mouse click inside this div, and clicking objects are working as well. But Everything is a little bit offset and the clickable area is bigger than the object itself.

So my question is how I can make this more accurate.

This code http://jsfiddle.net/phacer/FHD8W/1/ works in my browser but not in JSFiddle. 
So in this context, how can I click my objects?

I think line 180 is what is wrong.

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3((x / WIDTH) / 1 - 1, -(y / HEIGHT) / 1 + 1, 0.5);
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542175/three-js-ray-intersect-fails-by-adding-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your very close. The big problem is the use of the old r54 library. As of r58 Raycasting became a lot better. So check out this new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FHD8W/3/ I've removed the r54 link and added an external resource to the github.io.

Also, you were correct line 180 needed a slight tweak to look like this:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3((x / WIDTH) * 2 - 1, -(y / HEIGHT) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
```

That should do it

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much did it. But it only works if the div is fixed. Currently my div is absolute. Any idea of how to get that working?

Comment: Figured out a way to do it with a fixed position.

Comment: Glad to hear, yeah it can be finicky to get the right nested offset values to get the mouse coordinates over the element just right.