# Threejs issue with raycaster intersection

Tags: javascript, three.js

I wrote a code to intersect some object and worked fine until I put canvas with other div in html document. Now there are no intersection on the object. In this Live example:http://www.felpone.netsons.org/web-threejs/index1.html if you select on the right top the button cross and try to move the shape you can't. You can move shape if you put your mouse a little bit at right of the shape. So the intersection is completely wrong. I tried some solutions posted on stackoverflow but doesn't work. Can anyone help me to understand please? I am desperate.

In this other live example you can see how it should work : http://www.felpone.netsons.org/web-threejs/.
I tried with other solutions written on Stackoverflow but without result.

Maybe can depend by mouse coordinates:

```
mouse2D.x = ( ( event.clientX - renderer.domElement.offsetLeft ) / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
mouse2D.y = - ( ( event.clientY - renderer.domElement.offsetTop ) / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;
```

Here you can see the javascript code : http://www.felpone.netsons.org/web-threejs/stereos.js

Maybe can depend by:

I noticed that there are two differents dimension for canvas as  you can see in this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542175/three-js-ray-intersect-fails-by-adding-div

Comment: Tip: Avoid instantiating a new `Raycaster` and `Vector3` every time the mouse moves. Create one of each and reuse them.

Comment: the tag you circled in your screen shot above doesn't matter. What matters are the actual number (the top number you circled). And if the user resizes the browser, that top number may change. You need to query the containing offsets, per my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

event.clientX is relative to the browser window. You want the offset relative to the canvas. So you have to select the offset for each element containing the canvas.

This is some nice clean code that will do what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5932203/2195930

I use this code everytime I deal with a mouse over a canvas.

If you had a simpler test case, I'd try to mock up the whole solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change a code as follows:

```
var x = event.offsetX == undefined ? event.layerX : event.offsetX;
var y = event.offsetY == undefined ? event.layerY : event.offsetY;

mouse2D.x = ( x / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
mouse2D.y = - ( y / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;
```

Comment: Here you can see the javascript code : http://www.felpone.netsons.org/web-threejs/stereos.js

Answer (score 0):

In your DOM, canvas appears as

```
<canvas width="1139" height="975"></canvas>
```

That is from where your script is taking height and width.

However, the *real* dimensions of the canvas come from the

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

in your CSS.

I would remove one of them, so that the scripting can take the correct value without problems