# how to update the mouseposition on screen event on window resize?

Tags: javascript, three.js, trackball

What i need is to update the trackball controls to detect the mouse position event to a different screen size. I have an on click event which shows the position clicked point on screen with a yellow mark. If i refresh and try this event everything works fine, the event.x and event.y coordinates are correct referring at the window.innerWidth - window.innerHeight. When i resize the window the mark has an offset similar with the distortion of the resizing. If i resize the width only the mark has an offset at the axe(x). everything works using trackball controls. I am aware of the handleResize() function but it does not solved my problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27928662/4131583

Comment: thanks for providing info. I managed to solve that. The problem was that i was creating new variables on window resize and not using the old ones. The function that was showing the ball at the position clicked was using the value of the the other variable and not the one i created. Stupid mistake!thanks anyway!! :D