# Raycasting in Three.js coordinates seem to be off for some reason

Tags: three.js

For some reason, the raycaster is detecting the cube like 20 pixels above where the cube is and thus, when I click on the cube 20 pixels above where it is, the event is firing off. I want to click on any piece of the cube and have the event fire off. I'm putting my own spin on this example: http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html

Thanks friends

```
var scene, renderer, raycaster, camera;

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

var step = 0;

Init();
Animate();

function Init() {

   // document.addEventListener('mousemove', OnDocumentMouseMove, false);
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', OnDocumentMouseDown, false);


    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();


    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, -20, 10);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    //our lights
    var light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(-20,10,100);
    light.castShadow = true;

    scene.add(light);

    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(ambient);

    //create a floor
    var floor = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x484848 }));
    floor.receiveShadow = true;
    floor.position.set(0, 0, -0.1);
    scene.add(floor);


    //We are going to create color planes. If you click on one, it will change the box that color
    var redPane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3, 3), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 }));
    redPane.position.set(-7, 0, 0);
    redPane.receiveShadow = true;
    redPane.name ="REDPANE"
    scene.add(redPane);

    var bluePane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3, 3), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x190097 }));
    bluePane.position.set(-2, 0, 0);
    bluePane.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(bluePane);

    var yellowPane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3, 3), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xfcff00 }));
    yellowPane.position.set(3, 0, 0);
    yellowPane.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(yellowPane);

    var greenPane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(3, 3), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x004809 }));
    greenPane.position.set(8, 0, 0);
    greenPane.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(greenPane);
    //end of colored planes


    cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(3, 3, 3), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color:0x000000}));
    cube.name = "CUBEFRAME";
    cube.position.set(-5, 0, 3);
    cube.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(cube);
    //end of cube frame


    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor(0xeeeeee);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    $('#GameArea').append(renderer.domElement); 

}

function Animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(Animate);
    Render();

}

function Render() {

    AnimateCube();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function AnimateCube() {

    step += 0.01;
    scene.traverse(function (e) {

        if (e instanceof THREE.Mesh && e.name == "CUBEFRAME") {

          //  e.position.x = Math.sin(step) * (Math.exp(Math.cos(step)) - 2 * Math.cos(4 * step) - Math.pow(Math.sin(step / 12), 5));
          //  e.position.z = Math.cos(step) * (Math.exp(Math.cos(step)) - 2 * Math.cos(4 * step) - Math.pow(Math.sin(step / 12), 5)) + 5;;

        }
    });
}

/*

/****this is the event that is not working correctly!!!!***/
function OnDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = (event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);  
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        if(intersects[0].object.name == "CUBEFRAME"){
            var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(2, 2, 2), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xdddddd }));
            cube2.position.set(0, -5, 4);
            scene.add(cube2);

        }
    }

}

});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542175/three-js-ray-intersect-fails-by-adding-div/13544277#13544277

Comment: Thanks Langley! You are very helpful as usual