# Three.js Raycaster is offset when scollt the page

Tags: javascript, three.js

if a scene does not show up all over the page and you can sroll , Raycaster stops working and is offset by what you have scrolled .

Srollt to the side by 20 pixels down , you have 20 pixels below the object click , so that the object Raycaster recognizes correctly .

How fix i the problem?

Would be very grateful for help

Comment: This question is pretty hard to understand, I can guess what you mean, but it might help to provide a picture or link or get help cleaning up the english so we know what you mean.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542175/three-js-ray-intersect-fails-by-adding-div/13544277#13544277

Answer (score 8):

use the

```
var rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - rect.left ) / ( rect.width - rect.left ) ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( ( event.clientY - rect.top ) / ( rect.bottom - rect.top) ) * 2 + 1;
```

will works for you.
here is a demo, scroll to the bottom to click the cube.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.baidu.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<style>
body {
    font-family: Monospace;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0px;
}

#canvas {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 100px;
}

.border {
    padding:10px; 
    margin:10px;
 height:3000px;
 overflow:scroll;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="border">
  <div style="min-height:1000px;"></div>
 <div class="border">
  <div id="canvas"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<script>
// Three.js ray.intersects with offset canvas

var container, camera, scene, renderer, mesh,

    objects = [],
    
    count = 0,

    CANVAS_WIDTH = 200,
    CANVAS_HEIGHT = 200;

// info
info = document.createElement( 'div' );
info.style.position = 'absolute';
info.style.top = '30px';
info.style.width = '100%';
info.style.textAlign = 'center';
info.style.color = '#f00';
info.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
info.style.zIndex = '1';
info.style.fontFamily = 'Monospace';
info.innerHTML = 'INTERSECT Count: ' + count;
info.style.userSelect = "none";
info.style.webkitUserSelect = "none";
info.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
document.body.appendChild( info );

container = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

scene = new THREE.Scene();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, CANVAS_WIDTH / CANVAS_HEIGHT, 1, 1000 );
camera.position.y = 250;
camera.position.z = 500;
camera.lookAt( scene.position );
scene.add( camera );

scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );

var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
camera.add( light );

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( 
 new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200, 1, 1, 1 ), 
 new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color : 0x0080ff } 
) );
scene.add( mesh );
objects.push( mesh );

// find intersections
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

// mouse listener
document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', function( event ) {
    
 var rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - rect.left ) / ( rect.width - rect.left ) ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( ( event.clientY - rect.top ) / ( rect.bottom - rect.top) ) * 2 + 1;
  
 raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        
        info.innerHTML = 'INTERSECT Count: ' + ++count;
        
    }

}, false );

function render() {

    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

(function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();

})();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

the answer from Kris Roofe worked for me i just had to fix the mouse.x

```
mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - rect.left ) / ( rect.right - rect.left ) ) * 2 - 1;
```