# Limit Three.js' Raycaster to a specific part of the HTML. Avoid offsets

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, raycasting

I am using Three.js `Raycaster` for object picking.
My HTML is made of two main parts - Navigation Bar at the top (head section), and the bottom section, where my rendering takes place (body section).

My problem is that with this "constellation", I get an annoying offset for the `Raycaster`, about the size of the navigation bar height. So I thought it was the problem. When I tried taking out the navigation bar - I did get good results with no offset.

Obviously I want this code to run on multiple devices (may be strict to a specific browser, but not device), so "counting the pixels by hand" is no option.

I've tried putting the render part inside an `<iframe>`, it reduced the offset but still - it is there (any one knows why?).
I've thought on retrieving navigation bar's height and taking it into account when raycasting, but it seems to me like a patch. I rather have it the generic, robust way.

I've also tried `frameborder="0" scrolling="no"` in my `<iframe>` settings, didn't help.

**I am new to HTML/js/Three.js, so the answer might be simple, I take no offence.**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542175/three-js-ray-intersect-fails-by-adding-div

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40106019/6521116

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

Thanks to [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fek9ddg5/1/), lines [58-59] says that the mouse coordinates take the following values:

```
mouse.x=((event.clientX - renderer.domElement.offsetLeft)/renderer.domElement.width )*2-1;
mouse.y= -((event.clientY - renderer.domElement.offsetTop)/renderer.domElement.height)*2+1;
```

And as you can see - the `renderer` holds the offsets in its DOM meta data.
Apparently...

Feel free to comment.