# Clicking Objects in three.js when the canvas is not full screen r74

Tags: javascript, three.js

thank you for taking your time to answer my question.

I really can't find a good example on how to use raycaster in three JS in the version r74.

It seems to be a lot of changes between the versions r55 and r76... and many forums are talking and putting examples of minor versions of three..

can anyone give us an example of how to do it?

Im using angular and bootstrap by the way

this is what i've try:

**My View**

```
<div class="col-md-11">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 0px">
        <div class="canvas-zonas" ng-click="zonas.click($event)">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My Css (using stylus)**

```
.canvas-zonas
  height 67vh
```

**My Controller**

```
var = mouse = new THREE.Vector3();
var = raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var = canvas = document.querySelector(".canvas-zonas");

function clickObject(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      mouse.x= ((event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft)/canvas.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
      mouse.y=-((event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop)/canvas.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
      mouse.z = 0.5;
      raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
      var intersects = vm.raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
      console.info(intersects);
    }
```

So when I click my canvass and print the `Intersects` variable, sometimes I get [] an empty array even if a click the object and sometimes I get [object] even if I click outside the object.

I would like to show you guys a little bit of my camera config:

**My camera**

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight, 0.10, 1000)
camera.position.y = 20;
camera.position.z = 50;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

That's my camera config, and also, have in mind that I use a WEBGL as renderer

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
```

Also, have in mind that I have a resize event going on:

```
function listenResize() {
  window.bind('resize', function () {
    canvas = document.querySelector(".canvas-zonas");
    renderer.setSize(canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
    camera.aspect = (canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight);
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });
}
```

And finally, I'll post an image of what's going on:

**Image 1**

[image: In this case, I clicked inside the object but no objects were recuperated]

**Image 2**
[image: In this case, I clicked outside, and an object were recuperated]

thank you very much and excuse my last post. i've updated it!!!

Comment: What is your try so far? Might help to post code or to create an example on codepen.io

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes This example is working with the latest version. Full canvas though.

Comment: I have updated it! thank you very much!

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542175/three-js-ray-intersect-fails-by-adding-div/13544277#13544277

Comment: I've tried that before... doesn't work, besides that's a post from 3 years ago, and I'm using the r74 of Three JS

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem as you. After spending two days lurking around internet I finally found and tested this with good results:

```
let canvasBounds = this.renderer.context.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
this.mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - canvasBounds.left ) / ( canvasBounds.right - canvasBounds.left ) ) * 2 - 1;
this.mouse.y = - ( ( event.clientY - canvasBounds.top ) / ( canvasBounds.bottom - canvasBounds.top) ) * 2 + 1;
```

**Source**: [THREE.js Ray Intersect fails by adding div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542175/three-js-ray-intersect-fails-by-adding-div/13544277#13544277)

*Credits:*

- Y coordinate - "Kris Roofe" answer.
- X coordinate - "beepscore" who commented Kris Roofe's answer.

I hope it helps many folks like me.

Comment: Works for me, I have been breaking my head around this as well!

Comment: I would if I could! But alas, I am not the owner of this question. Definitely upvoted though!

Comment: Thanks for this solution!

Comment: It's 2023, and your solution perfectly worked :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe things have changed in the intervening years ... this mapping from mouse to (-1, 1) coordinates works for me despite responsive canvas shrinkage:

```
mouseVector.x = 2 * (e.x / canvas.offsetWidth) - 1;
mouseVector.y = 1 - 2 * ( (e.y - canvas.offsetTop) / canvas.offsetHeight );
mouseVector.z = 0.5 ;
```

Note that offsetHeight is NOT the same as height!  same for width.