# ThreeJS Raycaster doesn't find intersected objects if canvas isn't full screen

Tags: three.js

I created a scene with multiple objects in the canvas element with ThreeJS. I now want to change the material color of an object if the user clicks on it.

[image]

Excerpt of my Angular 5 component, which holds all the ThreeJS content:

```
public onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log("onMouseDown");
    event.preventDefault();

    var rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    mouse.x = (event.clientX / this.renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / this.renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;

    rayCaster.setFromCamera(mouse, this.camera);

    var intersects = rayCaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children);

    console.log("Scene has " + obj.length + " objects");
    console.log(intersects.length + " intersected objects found");

    intersects.forEach((i) => {
      i.object.material =
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xf1f11f});
    });
    this.render();
}
```

The problem is that the **mouse coordinates are not correct**, due to the distance between `canvas` element and the document outer edge. Whenever I click in the scene, an object right of the mouse will get the new material color.

Some information:
`this.renderer.domElement.clientWidth` holds the width of the canvas element

How to calculate the correct mouse coordinates if the canvas element isn't full screen?

Comment: This is less a three.js question and more a JavaScript/layout question.

Comment: Related: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542175/three-js-ray-intersect-fails-by-adding-div/13544277#13544277 Also, don't instantiate new Raycater, Vector2, Material unnecessarily.

Comment: @WestLangley How to use Raycaster without instantiating one? You mean to have a global Raycaster object instead of a local object inside the function?

Comment: Yes, or use a closure, so a single Raycaster instance can be reused. Change the color of an existing material; do not assign a new material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your flow is broken (your container is floated or manually positioned), then `clientX`/`clientY` will report "bad" values (relative to the page, rather than to the container like you might expect). The properties [`offsetX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX)/[`offsetY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetY) account for this by reporting values relative to the container on which the event was fired.

According to MDN, [support is limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX#Browser_compatibility), but my testing just now (01/22/2018) showed the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE all reported the correct values*. Just note that some browsers report integer values, while others may report double values.

**This may not hold true for Safari or mobile browsers. YMMV.*