# Moving objects parallel to projection plane in three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, projection, perspectivecamera

I want to move objects along a plane parallel to the projection plane with the mouse. This means during the movement the distance between any picked object and camera projection plane (not camera position) must remain constant. A similar question has been asked: [Mouse / Canvas X, Y to Three.js World X, Y, Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055214/mouse-canvas-x-y-to-three-js-world-x-y-z) , but unlike there I need a solution working for arbitrary camera angles and camera/object positions not only for the plane with z=0. It also has to work for orthographic projection. Now I created a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nmrNR/

the code in the mousemove event handler:

```
var v = new THREE.Vector3(
    (event.clientX/window.innerWidth)*2-1,
    -(event.clientY/window.innerHeight)*2+1,
    1
);
projector.unprojectVector(v,camera);
var dist = circle.position.sub(camera.position,circle.position),
    pos = camera.position.clone();
pos = pos.add(pos,
    v.sub(v,camera.position).normalize().multiplyScalar(dist.length())
);
```

The circle is following the mouse position but its distance to the camera position is constant so it is actually performing a spherical movement. When switching to the ortographic camera (click) it also does not follow the mouse position as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified the questioners excellent working version to work in a more current version (and a little more efficiently for me - just giving back, thanks.
At first I found myself using clone to avoid jumpy behavior. Then I noted moving the object back and forth crept it forward so I used an initial click position (to get the distanceTo).
There where also issues with warnings saying use addVectors and subVectors, but that was not necessary either.

```
camPos = cam.position;
var mv = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY/window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 1).unproject(cam);
var pos = camPos.clone(); 
pos.add(mv.sub(camPos).normalize().multiplyScalar(initalClickPos.distanceTo(camPos)));
```

Setting the target object being moved's position to pos will move it from the mouse move position in the current camera plane, but it does in a way rotate as the camera distance is maintained for the object in perspective view.

It still looks a little funky to me so I'm thinking maybe this can be improved further with add and sub being cleaner. Possibly as seen in the others answer posted.

I still have issues with an offset for where I initially click so the position center doesn't pop around, maybe setting the objects pivot temporarily is worth exploring.
This is working with r71.

Answer (score 0):

An older question which you might have long solved by now, here is an answer anyway.

You're not using a control like `OrbitControls` which possibly makes this slightly easier, if only for visualising it in your head. `OrbitControls` has not only the camera, but also a target object which directs the camera (it is always looking at it, and the y-axis is always up). The movement you want to achieve is perpendicular to the vector from camera to `target`, rather than the vector to your object which changes as you move the object and whose change explains the circular movement. And handily, `OrbitControls` provides the math you need.

From https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L147-L171, these functions compute a vector which are used to shift the camera and the target (which should work just as well for your object, though you'll probably need to invert the movement). Note that `this.object` is the camera.

```
// pass in distance in world space to move left
this.panLeft = function ( distance ) {

    var te = this.object.matrix.elements;

    // get X column of matrix
    panOffset.set( te[ 0 ], te[ 1 ], te[ 2 ] );
    panOffset.multiplyScalar( - distance );

    pan.add( panOffset );

};

// pass in distance in world space to move up
this.panUp = function ( distance ) {

    var te = this.object.matrix.elements;

    // get Y column of matrix
    panOffset.set( te[ 4 ], te[ 5 ], te[ 6 ] );
    panOffset.multiplyScalar( distance );

    pan.add( panOffset );

};
```

Code is from r.68, if you have an older version it might not work without modification.