# How to draw a line segment at run time using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to Three.js and I'm trying to implement the technique used in Microsoft Paint for drawing a line segment. I'm trying to get coordinates of a point onMouseDown then extend a line with onMouseMove until onMouseDown. Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

three.js is mainly for drawing in 3D. If you want to copy a 2D drawing application like paint then using the 2D canvas will probably be easier: `canvas.getContext("2d");`.

I will assume that you do want to draw in three.js. In which case I have put together **[this example](http://barkofthebyte.azurewebsites.net/demos/drawplane.htm)**. Follow these steps:

1. Click anywhere on the page and drag the mouse around to draw a line. The line is drawn on the z plane.
2. Click the Shapes button and notice how one shape is closer in and the other further, that is because one is above the z plane and the other behind.
3. Click the Rotate button, this will cause the camera to zoom out and rotate around the axes. Notice that when you pass through the z plane all your drawing is on that plane.

Have a look at the code, the main parts are:

You need to project the mouse click coordinates onto the plane. This is done with this function:

```
function get3dPointZAxis(event)
{
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(
                ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
                - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
                0.5 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    var dir = vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize();
    var distance = - camera.position.z / dir.z;
    var pos = camera.position.clone().add( dir.multiplyScalar( distance ) );    
    return pos;
}
```

Then draw the line from previous to this point:

```
geometry.vertices.push(lastPoint);
geometry.vertices.push(pos);
var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
scene.add(line);
```

Note that when you get close to passing through the z plane while rotating, the projection to Z is very far off and you go out of bounds, to prevent this the following check is done:

```
if( Math.abs(lastPoint.x - pos.x) < 500 && Math.abs(lastPoint.y - pos.y) < 500 && Math.abs(lastPoint.z - pos.z) < 500 )
```

For reference, I found information for projecting the mouse coordinate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13091694/746754) (SO answer) and [here](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html) (three.js sample).

**Update**

To draw a line from the mousedown position to the mouseup position see **[this demo](http://barkofthebyte.azurewebsites.net/demos/drawlineplane.htm)**. The code changes are to instead just do the draw between points on mouse up.

```
function stopDraw(event)
{
     if( lastPoint )
    {
        var pos = get3dPointZAxis(event);
        var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x0000ff
        });
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        if( Math.abs(lastPoint.x - pos.x) < 2000 && Math.abs(lastPoint.y - pos.y) < 2000 && Math.abs(lastPoint.z - pos.z) < 2000 )
        {
            geometry.vertices.push(lastPoint);
            geometry.vertices.push(pos);

            var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
            scene.add(line);
            lastPoint = pos;        
        }
        else
        {
            console.debug(lastPoint.x.toString() + ':' + lastPoint.y.toString() + ':' + lastPoint.z.toString()  + ':' + 
                        pos.x.toString() + ':' + pos.y.toString()  + ':' + pos.z.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The example gave a lot of idea. I was looking for drawing a straight line. The example gives effect of using a pen/pencil in Paint and not a line. Could u tell me how I can transform the above code to accomplish drawing a straight line from mouse down till mouse up event. Thanks in advance.

Comment: okay! Now I see. Thanks a ton! One doubt remains, that is, how to implement this code in the x-y plane? I know it is trivial, but I'm unable to get the result :(

Comment: @user3359133 The line will be drawn at z=0 which is the xy plane. If you mean how do you do this with just 2D then you should use the html 5 Canvas and not three.js. You would then use `canvas.getContext("2d");` and `LineTo`. See http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-lines/ and http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-line-caps/ and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/canvas_drawing_lines.htm.

Comment: how did u choose the value 2000 in this loc :- if( Math.abs(lastPoint.x - pos.x) < 2000 && Math.abs(lastPoint.y - pos.y) < 2000 && Math.abs(lastPoint.z - pos.z) < 2000 )
        {