# Three.js - Getting the X, Y, and Z coordinates of mouse click

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouse-coordinates

I'm using **version 68** of three.js.

I would like to click somewhere and get the X, Y, and Z coordinates. I followed the steps here, but they give me a Z value of 0: [Mouse / Canvas X, Y to Three.js World X, Y, Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055214/mouse-canvas-x-y-to-three-js-world-x-y-z)

Basically, if I have a mesh in the scene, and I click in the middle of it, I'm hoping to be able to calculate the same values as the position of that mesh. **This is just an example**. I know I could use raycasting and see if I collided with a mesh and then just check its position. However, I want this to work even if I didn't click a mesh.

Is this possible? Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j9ydgyL3/

In that jsfiddle, if I could manage to click in the center of that square, I'm hoping to calculate 10, 10,  10 for the X, Y, and Z values respectively because those are the coordinates of the square's position. Here are the two functions of concern:

```
function getMousePosition(clientX, clientY) {
    var mouse2D = new THREE.Vector3();
    var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3();
    mouse2D.x = (clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse2D.y = -(clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    mouse2D.z = 0.5;
    mouse3D = projector.unprojectVector(mouse2D.clone(), camera);
    return mouse3D;
    //var vector = new THREE.Vector3(
    //( clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
    //- ( clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
    //0.5 );

    //projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    //var dir = vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize();
    //var distance = - camera.position.z / dir.z;
    //var pos = camera.position.clone().add( dir.multiplyScalar( distance ) );
    //return pos;
}

function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var mouse3D = getMousePosition(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    console.log(mouse3D.x + ' ' + mouse3D.y + ' ' + mouse3D.z);
}
```

I left some of the other code I tried commented out. Please note that this commented-out code didn't work in the jsfiddle website, maybe because they're still using version 54 of three.js. It works fine on my machine with version 68.

**Edit:** To clarify, I would like to be able to get the coordinates no matter where the mouse is. I just used a mesh in this example because it's easy to verify if it works by seeing if the calculated coordinates are the same as the mesh's. What I would really like is for it to work without using raycasting on a mesh. For example, we could have it always printing the calculated coordinates to the console every time the mouse moves, no matter what is in the scene.

Comment: How are you going to find the Z coordinate without something like a mesh to click on? It could be anywhere from -Inf to +Inf. You really need something in there which provides coordinates to test for, and as per the answer you'd use the raycaster to check that.

Comment: @Leeft I'm not sure, that's why I asked if it's possible. if it really isn't possible, then feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it =)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [`THREE.Raycaster`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Raycaster) for this. When you set a list of `intersectObjects` you will be able to get an array of objects that intersected with the ray. So you can get the position from the 'clicked' object from returned list. [Check the updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/j9ydgyL3/2/).
I also changed your Three.js to version R68

For more advanced use of `THREE.RayCaster` check the examples at [Threejs.org/examples](http://threejs.org/examples/) like [this example with interactive cubes](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes).

Relevant code from the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9ydgyL3/2/):

```
function getMousePosition(clientX, clientY) {
    var mouse2D = new THREE.Vector3();
    var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3();
    mouse2D.x = (clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse2D.y = -(clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    mouse2D.z = 0.5;
    mouse3D = projector.unprojectVector(mouse2D.clone(), camera);
    return mouse3D;
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(
    (clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1,
    0.5);

    projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
    var dir = vector.sub(camera.position).normalize();
    var distance = -camera.position.z / dir.z;
    var pos = camera.position.clone().add(dir.multiplyScalar(distance));
    return pos;
}

function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var mouse3D = getMousePosition(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    console.log(mouse3D.x + ' ' + mouse3D.y + ' ' + mouse3D.z);

var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse3D.x, mouse3D.y, 1 );    
    raycaster.set( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children );
    if(intersects.length > 0){
        console.log(intersects[0].object.position);
    }
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: The fiddle does not appear to work as the cube geometry function appears to give an error?