# Three.js - Object follows mouse position

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a sphere in `Three.js` which has to follow the mouse whenever it moves, as displayed in [this example](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Sprite.html). The function that handles the mouse movement is the following:

```
function onMouseMove(event) {

    // Update the mouse variable
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    // Make the sphere follow the mouse
    mouseMesh.position.set(event.clientX, event.clientY, 0);
};
```

I attach a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atwfxdpd/)** with the complete code inside it, where you can see that according to the DOM, `mouseMesh` is undefined. Do you have an idea of what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For sphere to follow mouse, you need to convert screen coordinates to threejs world position. [Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055214/mouse-canvas-x-y-to-three-js-world-x-y-z).

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atwfxdpd/10/)

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.5);
vector.unproject( camera );
var dir = vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize();
var distance = - camera.position.z / dir.z;
var pos = camera.position.clone().add( dir.multiplyScalar( distance ) );
```

Comment: Again, thanks a ton! It helped me to finish my project

Comment: @uhura Could this jsFiddle be adjusted such that when the mousemove event is fired, move the camera instead of the object?

Comment: Sorry for the belated answer, but thank you so much for this fiddle! Really helped.

Comment: Hello!  This works, but what if I add orbit controls to the scene?  I want to manipulate my object in different projections.  So in this case, when I move the camera, your solution does not work correctly

Comment: I want the object to move around the screen space without perspective distortion

Comment: Can you explain what each line is doing? I'm particularly confused by this `distance`

Comment: What is the 0.5 for?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a THREE.Raycaster for this. When you set a list of intersectObjects you will be able to get an array of objects that intersected with the ray. So you can get the position from the 'clicked' object from returned list

Basically, you need to project from the 3D world space and the 2D screen space.
Renderers use projectVector for translating 3D points to the 2D screen. unprojectVector is basically for doing the inverse, unprojecting 2D points into the 3D world. For both methods you pass the camera you're viewing the scene through.
So, in this code you're creating a normalised vector in 2D space.