# ThreeJS. Intersection between Ray and plane Z (z=0)

Tags: three.js

Each Raycaster Ray object has an origin and a direction (raycaster.ray).
What I want is find intersection between a ray and the plane in which all points have z = 0 (z plane).
To create a proper plane and then using raycaster on it is not a solution.
I would know what is the best way to find this intersection.

Comment: Please consider re-wording your question. You can certainly check the closest points of an axis (defined as a ray) and another ray. Or you can define a proper plane (there is no "Z axis plane"), and raycast against that. But until we know exactly what you're trying to do, we can only guess at your intention, and if we guess wrong, our answers will be wrong.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/13091694/1461008